# Bounds on the Number of Edges in a Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

everyone:

I'm working on the following problem, and not getting anywhere. I was hoping someone could give me some direction on thought process or some facts about graphs that may be useful so I can solve the problem.

**Here is the problem:**

---

Let G be an undirected graph with $n$ vertices. Let $\Delta(G)$ be the maximum degree of any vertex in $G$, $\delta(G)$ be the minimum degree of any vertex in $G$, and m be the number of edges in G. Prove that
$\frac{\delta(G)\cdot n}{2} \leq m \leq  \frac{\Delta(G)\cdot n}{2}$

---

**Here is my work:**

---

Multiplying each side of the equation by 2 we get:
$\delta(G)\cdot n \leq 2m \leq  \Delta(G)\cdot n$

We know that if $m$ is the total number of edges in $G$ and $G$ has $V$ total vertices where $v$ is a vertex in $V$, then $2m=\sum_{v\in V} deg(v)$

---

That's about as far as I can get. I've gone down a couple roads of thought but don't wind up anywhere. Any direction would be greatly helpful. Thank you all so much!

Comment: But, for every $v\in V$ you have $\delta(G)\le\deg(v)\le\Delta(G)$... you just need to sum across all $v\in V$...

Comment: Hey, @StinkingBishop

Thank you for your reply. Could you clarify a bit more what you mean by "you just need to sum across all $v \in V$? Also, are you stating it's a fact that $\delta(G) \leq deg(v) \leq \Delta(G)$? The reason I ask is because that's not a fact I have been given or shown. How can I know that's true?

Comment: I have made the observation that $\delta(G) \leq \Delta(G) \leq \sum_{v\in V} deg(v)$, but that hasn't helped me at all

Comment: Your problem states "Let $\Delta(G)$ be the *maximum* degree of any vertex in $G$, $\delta(G)$ be the *minimum* degree of any vertex in $G$" ... The rest is just simple arithmetic. ($n$ numbers, each between $\delta(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$, how big is their sum?).

Comment: They don't provide a sum or anything. What I posted is what they gave me.

Comment: But ... *you* have provided the sum $\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v)$. That is the sum I am talking about. It lies between $\delta(G)\cdot n$ and $\Delta(G)\cdot n$ because it has $n$ terms and each of the terms is a degree of a vertex, and therefore is between $\delta(G)$ and $\Delta(G)$...

Comment: OHHHHHHHH I see, because $\delta(g)\cdot n$ is the sum of the degree of all the vertices if they all had the same lowest degree, and same sorta thing for $\Delta(g) \cdot n$.

Comment: Yes. That is it.

Comment: Thank you so much!